# The Beltrami equation and Neumann series

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, quasiconformal

Let $\mu:  \mathbb{C} \to D(0,1).$ A quasiconformal map is a $W^{1}_{2,loc}-$solution to the Beltrami equation $\bar{\partial}f = \mu \partial f$. In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11602) paper, the authors remark that one can formally solve for $f$ in this equation by the Neumann series $$\bar{\partial}f = \mu + \mu T \mu + \mu T \mu T \mu + \cdots$$ where $T$ is the Beurling transform $$Tf(z) = \partial\left(\frac{\bar{\partial}f}{\partial z}\right)^{-1}(z) = -\frac{1}{\pi} p.v \int_{\mathbb{C}}\frac{f(w) \ \mathrm dw}{(z-w)^2}.
$$
I cannot see how, even formally, this is true, and no source I can find shows how to do this. What is the heuristic behind this?

Answer (score 5):

The story of the solution of the Betrami equation using the Beurling transformation in $L^2$ has an elegant and elementary explanation in:

> Adrien Douady and X. Buff, *Le théorème d’intégrabilité des structures
> presque complexes*, **The Mandelbrot set, theme and variations**, London
> Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., vol. 274, Cambridge Univ. Press,
> Cambridge, 2000, pp. 307–324. MR 1765096

I can't see how it becomes precisely what you have quoted, but is similar. If we let $f=(I-\mu L)^{-1}\mu$, where $L$ the Beurling transform, then $(I-\mu L)f=\mu$, so $f=\mu+\mu L f$. If $\varphi$ satisfies $\bar\partial \varphi=f$, then $\bar\partial (z+\varphi)=f=\mu+\mu L f=\mu+\mu\bar\varphi=\mu(\bar z+\bar\varphi)$. So $z+\varphi$ is the solution you are looking for, modulo various details explained clearly in that paper.